# Phalcon devtools not working

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm attempting to install Phalcon Dev Tools on OSX. I have Phalcon installed and it works fine.

I've followed the instructions from here: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/mactools.html

When I run the command `phalcon` in the terminal I get the following output:

```
Phalcon Developer Tools Installer
Make sure phalcon.sh is in the same dir as phalcon.php and that you are     running this with sudo or as root.
Installing Devtools...
Working dir is: /Users/me/phalcon-tools
Done. Devtools installed!
```

Now how do I use the devtools? When I enter `phalcon commands` the output is exactly the same as above, and continues to tell me that it's installed.

Am I missing something here?

I noticed in the `phalcon.sh` script, at the end it had:

```
if check_install; then
    php "$PTOOLSPATH/phalcon.php" $*
fi
```

So, if check_install passes, run `phalcon.php`. I've tried to run this script manually and nothing happens at the terminal.

`$PTOOLSPATH` is defined. I confirmed this using `echo $PTOOLSPATH`.

My `/usr/bin/env php` is correct and points to MAMP's PHP. I have Phalcon installed using MAMP at the moment. My PHP is correct:

```
which php
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.23/bin/php
```

Inspecting the `phalcon.php` script, and using xdebug, I detected the issue to be lying here:

```
if (!extension_loaded('phalcon')) {
    throw new Exception(
        sprintf(
            "Phalcon extension isn't installed, follow these instructions to install it: %s",
            Script::DOC_INSTALL_URL
        )
    );
}
```

So the Phalcon extension isn't loaded. Not sure why it's not printing the output of the exception in the terminal. But, PHP's error log is showing:

```
[21-May-2015 22:37:48 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Phalcon\Script' not found in /Users/me/phalcon-tools/phalcon.php on line 41
```

Now I'm stumped.

**Edit:**

Running `php -m` showed me Phalcon isn't installed. Which is odd, because I am using Phalcon in my web application, and it works fine. As you can see, I've loaded the extension in the `php.ini`.

[image]

The PHP version I'm using is:

```
PHP 5.5.23 (cli) (built: Apr  9 2015 19:29:27)
```

As you can see, Phalcon is in the correct directory:

```
ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.23/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212
apcu.so
imagick.so
phalcon.so
...
```

And as you can see from `phpinfo()` it's installed ...

[image]

The following commands both give different results too:

Shows Phalcon as installed:

```
echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" | php > phpinfo.txt && cat phpinfo.txt | grep phalcon
```

Shows Phalcon not installed:

```
php -m
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

After trying a lot, I found out that the code shown in the [reference](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/mactools.html) is wrong:

```
ln -s ~/phalcon-tools/phalcon.sh ~/phalcon-tools/phalcon
chmod +x ~/phalcon-tools/phalcon
```

The proper way can be found in the [github repo](https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools):

```
ln -s ~/phalcon-devtools/phalcon.php /usr/bin/phalcon
chmod ugo+x /usr/bin/phalcon
```

Basically, the link shouldn't be the script but the php file. Fixing that, I could run the dev tool properly.

Comment: im geting these issue `ubuntu@ip-000-31-14-000:~$ sudo chmod ugo+x /usr/bin/phalcon
chmod: cannot operate on dangling symlink ‘/usr/bin/phalcon’`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you. and I solved it as long as I add this two line into my ~/.bash_profile file.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/scott/phalcon-tools
export PTOOLSPATH=/Users/scott/phalcon-tools
```

At first, I only add the first line into .bash_profile, and I got the same information with you.

Answer (score 0):

May be in command line ini file phalcon is not installed so it is throwing error.

just type this command in terminal .

```
php --ini
```

then check the output the interesting line is

```
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

now try to check that

```
phalcon.so
```

is loaded there as well or not.

as for web and cli there are different phalcon.so file is provided so we need to inlcude "**phalcon.so**" in both files.

so **phalcon.so** is included in your web php.ini so its running smooth there and not it command line i guess.